# Determine whether $f''(x)>0$ or not in a given interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:[0,4]\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ be a twice differentiable function.Further,let $f(0)=1,f(2)=2,f(4)=3$. Then which of the following can be regarded as true?

$A:$there does not exist any $x_1\in(0,2)$ such that $f'(x_1)=\frac{1}{2}$

$B:$there exist $x_2\in(0,2)$ and $x_3\in(2,4)$ such that $f'(x_2)=f'(x_3)$

$C:f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,4)$

$D:f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in(0,4)$

---

By Lagrange mean value theorem,we can prove that $f'(x_2)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(x_3)=\frac{f(4)-f(2)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.Hence,$B$ is true.For similar reason $A$ is not true.

But I don't know how to verify the last two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f''\left(x\right)>0
 $ for all $x\in\left(0,4\right)
 $ then $f'\left(x\right)
 $ is a monotone increasing function. But this contradicts $B$. Similar argument for the other inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $g$ =$f'$.

You have shown that there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$.

Apply Rolle's theorem.